# Site works ok but composer complains about unmet requirements. Do I have a problem?

Tags: 8, composer

### UPDATE: I am not going to continue to troubleshoot this.  Composer is working OK in my local site, so I'm going to change my approach to deployment and stop running composer in my staging site.  Instead I will run composer locally, commit core & vendor to the git project, and deploy all code to staging with git.

---

I am trying to get my permissions right, so I don't have to run composer as root.  As part of this process, I deleted vendor, core and composer.lock and ran composer install with my non-root user.  The site appears to be working fine, despite this message composer displayed:

```
  Problem 1
    - drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master

    etcetera
```

What does this mean?  Is my site OK, or did I take a wrong turn?

I'm not sure why the composer message references "drupal/core 8.2.x-dev".  Here is the "require" section of my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/features": "^3.8",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.8",
    "drupal/webform": "^5.1",
    "drupal/config_installer": "^1.8",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.1",
    "drupal/media_entity_browser": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/file_browser": "^1.1",
    "drupal/admin_menu_search": "^1.0",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.26",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
    "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4",
    "drupal/contribute": "^5.0@beta",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.6",
    "drupal/facets": "^1.3",
    "drupal/field_group": "^1.0",
    "drupal/form_placeholder": "^1.0",
    "drupal/formblock": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/glazed_helper": "^1.3",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^1.29",
    "drupal/imce": "^1.7",
    "drupal/insert_block": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/linkit": "^4.3",
    "drupal/login_emailusername": "^1.1",
    "drupal/material_admin": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.0",
    "drupal/minifyhtml": "^1.6",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.6",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.3",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.3",
    "drupal/require_login": "^2.0",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.11",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.0",
    "drupal/simplenews": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/tfa": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/token": "^1.5",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0",
    "drupal/view_unpublished": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/viewport": "^1.1",
    "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.4",
    "drupal/workflow_state_config": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1",
    "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.4",
    "drupal/taxonomy_access_fix": "^2.6",
    "drupal/text_summary_options": "^1.0",
    "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "^2.2",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_file": "^1.1",
    "drupal/entityqueue": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/module_missing_message_fixer": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "ckeditor/autogrow": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/codemirror": "^1.17",
    "ckeditor/fakeobjects": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/image": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/link": "^4.8",
    "codemirror/codemirror": "^5.36",
    "jquery/geocomplete": "^1.7",
    "jquery/icheck": "^1.0",
    "jquery/image-picker": "^0.3.0",
    "jquery/inputmask": "^3.3",
    "jquery/intl-tel-input": "^12.1",
    "jquery/rateit": "^1.1",
    "jquery/select2": "^4.0",
    "jquery/timepicker": "^1.11",
    "jquery/toggles": "^4.0",
    "jquery/word-and-character-counter": "^2.5",
    "progress-tracker/progress-tracker": "^1.4",
    "signature_pad/signature_pad": "^2.3",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.2",
    "drupal/crop": "^1.5",
    "drupal/advagg": "^3.5",
    "drupal/advagg_js_minify": "^3.5",
    "drupal/advagg_css_minify": "^3.5",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups_admin": "^1.3",
    "drupal/chosen": "^2.6",
    "drupal/chosen_field": "^2.6",
    "drupal/content_export_csv": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/contentimport": "^4.1",
    "drupal/event": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/entity_reference_views_select": "^1.3",
    "drupal/imce_search_plugin": "^1.0",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/job": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/media_bulk_upload": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/memcache": "^2.0",
    "drupal/purge_ui": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge_processor_lateruntime": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge_tokens": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.1",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^2.5",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups": "^1.3",
    "drush/drush": "^9.5",
    "drupal/we_megamenu": "^1.5",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.5",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/purge": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/address": "^1.4",
    "drupal/acquia_connector": "^1.16",
    "drupal/purge_purger_http": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/content_sync": "^2.1",
    "drupal/console": "~1.0",
    "drupal/devel": "^2.0",
    "drupal/core": "8.6.13"
},
```

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?

Comment: @mpdonadio  It was an upgrade from Drupal 8.6.10 to 8.6.13.

Comment: Can you show what `composer why-not drupal/core:8.6.13` lists?  This may narrow the problem down better.  As a side note, I suspect there is a Symfony related dependency problem.  Personally I always use `webflo/drupal-core-strict`, pinned top the same version as core, which tends to prevent dependency problems.

Comment: Temporarily removing drush and drupal console can also help.

Comment: Does anyone know what this part means: "remove drupal/drupal dev-master".  In a literal sense, what is that telling me?  What is "drupal/drupal dev-master"?

Comment: @mpdonadio  The output from that why-not command is 'There is no installed package depending on "drupal/core" in versions not matching 8.6.13'.

Comment: @mpdonadio  I tried adding "webflo/drupal-core-strict": "8.6.13" to the require section of my composer.json, and then removed composer.lock, core and vendor and ran composer update.  The output is exactly the same as it is in my question, unfortunately: "drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ..."

Comment: Very odd.  How about `composer why drupal/core:8.2.x-dev`?  Since it isn't in your main composer.json, `drupal/core:8.2.x-dev` is somewhere in the dependency tree.  You can also read the lockfile and search for that and see what section / package is listing it.

Comment: @mpdonadio That command gives the same result, unfortunately.  I don't see anything in the composer.lock that seems relevant.  Here is the composer.lock: https://pastebin.com/eGBV99Ae

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a composer issue. Sometimes composer isn't that great at handling complex dependencies. If you want to get rid of the error, many people have success going "nuclear":

1. Back up your site completely
2. Remove core folder, vendor folder and composer.lock - E.g. if you are on linux `$ sudo rm -rf docroot/core vendor composer.lock`
3. Run composer update `$ composer update`

Comment: "Sometimes composer isn't that great at handling complex dependencies."  Which is its one job.  This is kind of like saying sometimes Chrome isn't great at browsing websites.  In any case, it sounds like you think there is no real problem, just a false positive error message?

Comment: @arnoldbird The number of dependencies that core brings in can expose bugs and other quirks in composer.

Comment: @100pic I completed the three steps you suggested, but I get the exact same output as I included in my question.  It's the same "drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ..."

Comment: @arnoldbird hmm, maybe try deleting the composer.lock file and then `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` ? Just a stab in the dark. Not sure why updating drupal with composer is so troublesome!

Comment: @100pic  Same result, unfortunately.